# How do I translate a gradient at runtime without recreating the shader?

Tags: android

I would like to draw a line with a smooth cutout in it. The cutout would consist of a grading fading out, and a gradient fading in. At runtime, I would like to translate this cutout across the line in response to user input.

I can draw the gradient using a LinearGradient instance. However, the gradient descriptors are defined at instance creation time. I don't want to recreate the shader every time the position changes.

```
int[] colors = { Color.WHITE, Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.WHITE};
cutoutPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 100, colors, new float[]{0, 0.4f, 0.6f, 1}, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));

void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawLine(..... cutoutPaint);
}
```

My question is, how can I translate this cutout along the line, without recreating the shader?